# how can I play the songs one after another in windows media player

Tags: c#, windows, media

I'm developing a VS 2008 C# coded Windows media player using axWindows media player control available in Visual Studio. I have stored the song paths in a SQL server 2005 database and I'm able to play one song at a time now. I want my application to play the songs from the database continuously without asking anything. How can I achieve this task , please suggest me the way to do so.

Comment: Can you please post your code, so that we know what you did wrong?

Comment: How is this not a real question? It's nowhere near the least clear question posted in the past few minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either pass in the song list as a whole playlist, or you may want to use the PlayStateChange event to listen for when the current song ends and then load up the next song when that happens.

Comment: Sorry to be too late to post my comments back to StackOverflow.Thank you Mr. Brandon Bodnar (my be your name mistakenly pronounced, sorry for that). After all I did that job one yr. before.